# Using GROUP_CONCAT (MySQl) and WM_CONCAT (Oracle) in Propel

Tags: php, mysql, oracle10g, propel, group-concat

Is there a function in **Propel ORM** which allows me to use something like a `GROUP_CONCAT` (or `WM_CONCAT`) aggregation on both **Oracle10g** and **MySQL** databases?

Well, I know that I can write my own switch, but that's not desirable for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, use `withColumn()` instead and put your Oracle function in it :)